# Connecting to another server by bash script

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

On server A I have a script in bash with a conditional. If the conditional is true, a connection is made to server B and httpd is reloaded. The script runs in cron and everything works correct.

I don't know what happens when the script ends, the connection to server 2  closes automatically? Now I in server B I don't see that user who loggin from server A is logged. That is correct ?

```
isInFile=$(something)

if [ $isInFile -eq 1 ]; then

ssh -p 1234 -i ~/.config/username/.ssh/id_rsa username@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

sudo systemctl reload httpd

fi
```

Comment: Does the script ever end when the condition is true? What does the script output (both out and err) say?

Comment: I found solution my problem. I added parameter -t and now connection is closed after did command.
ssh -p 1234 -i ~/.config/username/.ssh/id_rsa username@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -t 'sudo systemctl reload httpd'